# Google reports Email Log Search API

Tags: google-admin-sdk, google-reporting-api, google-email-audit-api

In the admin panel, one can go to Reports and run an Email Log Search.
I wasn't able to find an API (hopefully RESTful) for this. Can anyone point me in the right direction?
I know there is Email Audit Logs but that's not quite what I'm looking for. An audit process requires a specific mailbox to be audited whereas I'm looking for an organization-level search. Thanks.

Comment: If what you're looking for is not found in [Email Audit API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/email-audit/), there's a chance that this may not be supported yet and you will have to resort to your own implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Not an API, but you can install an [application](https://workspace.google.com/marketplace/app/gat+/199329000796) for GSuite domains that lets you search the whole domain mailboxes.