# Is there a way to run email to/from search via the Google Email API?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-api, google-workspace

I haven't been able to find any information on an API that allows to perform an email API log search on G-Suite. For security, we want to be able to have to run a search for, say, all emails originating from user@ourgsuitedomain.com and all emails coming to. While this is possible in admin.google.com, I want to know if it's possible via an API.

All I found about this is [outdated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40611327/google-reports-email-log-search-api) [threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31040937/google-email-log-search-api) right here on SO.

Answer (score 1):

The only option to audit emails is to create an email monitor with the Email Audit API, in the case that you may want to implement ver singular search criteria, consider that the API may not fit your requirements completely. You can find the documentation at https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/email-audit/